# How to Sum calulated fields

Tags: jmx

I‘d like to ask I question that here that I think would be easy to some people.

Ok I have query that return records of two related tables. (One to many)

In this query I have about 3 to 4 calculated fields that are based on the fields from the 2 tables.

Now I want to have a group by clause for names and sum clause to sum the calculated fields but it ends up in error message saying:

“You tried to execute a query that is not part of aggregate function”

So I decided to just run the query without the totals *(ie no group by , sum etc,,,) 
:
And then I created another query that totals my previous query.  ( i.e. using group by clause for names and sum for calculated fields… no calculation here) This is fine ( I use to do this) but I don’t like having two queries just to get summary total. Is their any other way of doing this in the design view and create only one query?.
I would very much appreciate.

Thankyou:

JM

Comment: can you post your SQL please?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the query is thinking the calculated fields need to be part of the grouping or something. You might need to look into sub-querying.

Can you post the sql (before and after). It would help in getting an understanding of what the issue is.